# Issue with Colorbox with Cookie and setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, colorbox

Trying to get a cookie setup with this Colorbox script.  Everything works except the cookie portion and I believe it's because of the order of the items in the script.  I'm wanting the cookie to expire in 1 day. Here's the script:  Any help is appreciated!  Thank you!

```js
<script src="Navigation/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Navigation/jquery.slimmenu.min.js"></script>
<script src="ColorBox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
<!--
$(window).load(function() {
      $('ul.slimmenu').slimmenu(
{
    resizeWidth: '750', /* Navigation menu will be collapsed when document width is below this size or equal to it. */
    collapserTitle: 'Main Menu', /* Collapsed menu title. */
    animSpeed: 'medium', /* Speed of the submenu expand and collapse animation. */
    easingEffect: null, /* Easing effect that will be used when expanding and collapsing menu and submenus. */
    indentChildren: false, /* Indentation option for the responsive collapsed submenus. If set to true, all submenus will be indented with the value of the option below. */
    childrenIndenter: '&nbsp;' /* Responsive submenus will be indented with this character according to their level. */
 });
 
$(document).ready(function() {
 setTimeout(function() {
  $.colorbox({width:"75%", height:"75%", iframe:true, href:"/Announcements/CurrentAnnouncement.htm"});
  }, 3000); // After 3 secs
  
 setTimeout(function () { $.fn.colorbox.close(); }, 10000); // After 10 secs
});

    if ($.cookie('test_status') != '1')
    {
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            alert('foo');
            jQuery.cookie('test_status', '1', { expires: 1}); 
        }, 1000);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: remove `});` from the lase

Comment: Doing that breaks my slimmenu logic, that I didn't include in the original code.  I can re-edit with the full amount, however don't believe that's the issue.